# problems arise when designing database for fashion online shop

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, data-modeling

I designed my database for customers, products, and orders... I came up with 5 tables:
**1. customers**

- customer_id
- email
- password
- first_name
- last_name
- registration_date

**2.  products**

- product_id
- type_id (refers to type table)
- price
- size

**3.   Type**

- type_id
- name
- description

**4.   order**

- order_id
- customer_id  (refers to customer table)
- total_price
- total_tax
- date

**5.  order_item**

- order_item_id
- order_id
- product_id (refers to product_id)
- quantity
- price

I realized that shoes/t-shirt/shirt will have a size, but accessories don't...

Should I add 1 more table like `product_description`? so in the product table, there will be `product_description_id`. If the `product_description_id` is 0, then it doesn't have any more description like size, but if its not 0 then it has...

**EDITED**
guys guys, i have 1 more problem, because i want to let the customer to buy more than 1 item(more than 1 type) in a time :s does above table can do that? i meant, will it fit that situation? i already edited the table, sry if im asking too much :D

Comment: have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Normal_forms

Comment: @Mohur you can do both have a product_description_id and if it is null (empty) then it don't have one.

Comment: @dmaij these tables seem pretty 3NF to me.

Comment: I'd change `order_log` to `order_log_entries` or something like that. Each row is not a log; each row is a long entry. Also, I would change `order_description` to `orders` and have a separate `order_products` table that joins `products` to `orders`.

Comment: Also, I recommend the book Database in Depth by C.J. Date.

Comment: @Jan, it does, but it will never be able to create an order existing of more than 1 different item. The design should be reconsidered.

Comment: @JasonSwett: Orders have to retain product information, most importantly -- price and tax -- at the time of sale.  For example, what if tax changes from 2 to 5 percent?  Your modeling would retro-actively change the tax for any historical data.  Worth mentioning -- orders and line items.  Line items are what's currently called `order_description`.

Comment: @Mohur the fact is that there is plenty of ways to design a Product, Order, Transaction database and it will depend on your requirements, start with a written description of what you need and use the nouns as tables and expand from there, this will open up discussion of different ways so you may wish to create a concrete question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add the product descriptions to your product table:

- product_id
- type_id
- size etc

And I would introduce an order table:

- order_id
- customer_id
- total price
- total tax 
  etc

and have your order_description renamed to order_item with

- order_id
- product_id
- quantity

etc

Comment: so i should add the size in the product table and make accesories size to become 0 (means fits for all), hmm your order table and order_item table helps alot! but may i ask what is the reason u add size to product table and not to make another table (product_description)?

Comment: Because the product <-> product description is probably a 1-1 relationship. If you want, you can split these, that's up to you. You can then reuse product descriptions, but consider whether this will happen in your case.

Comment: i have updated my table, but what if a customers want to buy more than 1 type of item at a time? should i use the same order_id in the order_item?

Comment: The idea of an order is that it contains more than 1 item. Per item you can keep track of quantity, tax rate and price (and quantity*price etc), per order you can keep track of total price, total tax, order number for tracking etc. The same goes for invoices and quotes etc. As a tip I would say, write everything down with maximum detail (lookat others) and design your tables from there.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to consider oneTomany table because one order may contain more than one article.

In this case you need a table that contains Order_Id,  Product_Id, possibly a second containing Client_ID and Order_ID  and so on ...  Try to individuate all cases where you need a one to many or many to many relationships.

Inany case the suggested readings in the previous answers will helps  you a lot.